# Moving pages created at wrong publication in blueprint

Tags: 2011, content-manager

I know its not possible to copy/paste between publications but our client has just spent two days creating structure groups and pages in a parent publication when they should have been in  a child publication.

Is there anyway to "move" these pages?

I just tried to be sneaky with Content Porter by exporting from the parent, renaming publications and importing but that reset the child publications blueprint settings and I couldn't get them back (ended up having to recreate the child publication again).

I could write something clever with the core service but pushed for time.

If I went to SDL Support is there a db script or something I can use?

Cheers

Comment: You can use Content Porter, If you try just `children only` you will be good. Nice Article : http://monicamanzano.blogspot.com/2012/12/moving-items-around-within-single.html. I had success in the past when I tried.

Comment: Sure I tried that. Will that option stop my renamed child publications settings from being over written?

Comment: Yes.. It will. In your case, also rename the parent `Structure Group`, so the child publication import wont complain of duplicate names. Step 1: Export , Step 2 : Rename Parent and Childs, Step 3: Import child only..

Comment: Thinking out loud here - I guess you could change the position of the publication in the blueprint and swap with the children through some small, carefully done steps. Of course it would swap more than just the pages/content, but if that's all that is contained (local) in the publication it might work...

Comment: Nuno's thinking out loud sparked another option.. If you just copy the structure group in child and paste it in the child publication you will have same set of pages in child publication with new structure group. Now you can go to the parent and remove the original structure group, then rename the copied structure group to original name. thoughts?

Comment: This will work, and is simple & clean. +10

Comment: Moving pages down a tree is easy. Up... not so much.

Comment: Wow - think I'll go with Ram's suggestion. Feel free to add as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moving the pages from Parent Publication to Child Publication will be relatively easy with some simple steps.

1. Copy the structure group(created in Parent publication) from child publication.
2. Paste it in the child publication you will have same set of pages in child publication with new structure group.
3. Now you can go to the parent and delete(if published, unpublish first) the original structure group, then rename the copied structure group to original name.

Hope this helps. This process works only if you want to move the pages downwards in the blueprint chain, not upwards.

Answer (score 4):

There's a cross publication copy tool that might be suitable for your copying problem.

I've once written a custom page to perform something similar (and it works quite well), but it was written using the TDSE, I'm happy to drop it somewhere for you to have a look at?

Thanks

John

Comment: if you send me your email address (i'm john@contentbloom.com)